# Duda sobre host

Tags: android, sql, ios, azure

Que tal, les comento, soy programador junior en sistemas Android y iOS estoy desarrollando una aplicación y web la cual requiere mucho flujo de datos y almacenamiento. Para que se den una idea pretende ser una aplicación y web parecida a eBay u OLX. Es decir, muchos usuarios en línea, chats y muchos datos e imágenes en el servidor.

Lo que no se, y acá viene mi duda, es que necesito para hostear todo esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Lo más probable es que cierren esta pregunta, por estar basada en opiniones, pero lo que necesitas es un buen servidor, ya que la aplicación no requiere tanto, lo que requiere robustez es el servidor para atender las peticiones y almacenar la información.

Comment: Pensá en hacerlo escalable, que te permita arrancar con poco y que no sea un dolor de cabeza muy fuerte agregar mas recursos a medida que necesitas.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Javi!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!